# Force the OK click event on MessageBox.Show()

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dialog, messagebox

Looks like the only way to auto print without user pop up window is to have the line `MessageBox.Show("print")`

When this line of code is there and you click "ok" it avoids the pop up print window if you put `Me.Close()` after dispose line.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-print-with-a-webbrowser-control

My question is... is there a way to force the OK click on the MessageBox so that the auto print happens?

I tried doing the following with a blank Form2 to force the ok but didn't work:

```
 Dim dr As DialogResult = Form2.ShowDialog(Me)
    Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK

    If Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK Then
        Thread.Sleep(2000)
        webBrowserForPrinting.Dispose()

        Me.Close()
    End If
```

[image]

Comment: The webbrowser control displays no 'user pop up window' for me, so I dont understand what you are asking.  Seems redundant to have a message box display while the printer is churning out pages, so whats the point?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. I want to close the form after the auto print but if I don't use the MessageBox.Show() it will show print popup window. If I don't use the MessageBox.Show() and do Me.Close() after Displose it doesn't auto print either @Plutonix

Comment: I've tested running PrintHelpPage() in the load event and shown event

Comment: What does this "pop up print window" look like that you're getting?

Comment: I have no context for any of that - what is `Me` - the form with the webbrowser?  `webBrowserForPrinting.Print()` will print the page without any popups at all for me.  If pop up wondow(s) are a problem, they are likely something your code is doing.  Also, you can edit comments for up to 5 minutes after posting so you dont have to ping someone every 52 seconds with afterthoughts

Comment: When the `MessageBox.Show("print")` code isn't there the normal print popup shows [see update] @Plutonix

Comment: We're going to have to see your print code.

Comment: it is the exact code in the link. All I do is call `PrintHelpPage` inside the load event

Comment: The exact code in the link doesnt pop up anything for me.  I think that may only come up if there is no default printer or something similar

Comment: I have a default set. So when you comment out `MessageBox.Show("print")` that print pop up image I uploaded doesn't show up correct?

Comment: Correct.  I don't get any pop-up either.  Printer prints.

Comment: `All I do is call PrintHelpPage inside the load event `.  That is not what the linked code does.  It prints from the `DocumentCompleted ` event

Comment: The code doesn't show how the functions are initially executed so I attempted to run the PrintHelpPage from the asp.net pages load event

Comment: You tagged this WinForms, not ASP.Net.

Comment: meant to say winforms... my url is a asp.net page. typo